# Pybind11 linux building tests failure - 'Could not find package configuration file pybind11Config.cmake and pybind11-config.cmake'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, c++11, pybind11

I'm trying to build pybind11 tests on a linux box. I downloaded the source and do the following -

`cd pybind11-master
 cd tests
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..`

I get the errors - 
` Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pybind11" with any of 
  the following names:

pybind11Config.cmake
  pybind11-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "pybind11" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "pybind11_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "pybind11" provides a separate development package or SGK, be sure it has been installed
`

I followed this link - http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/basics.html and did as per the instruction in section 'Compiling Test Cases for linux/mac'

I am not sure how to proceed. Any pointers are helpful.

Comment: I hit the same problem, after installed pybind11 and tried to use it in cmake.

Answer (score 2):

I already hit the same problem after installing pybind11 by `pip install pybind11`.
I'll post here my solution in case someone ends up here.

I installed following [this link](https://apolo-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/software/scientific_libraries/pybind/pybind11/index.html), everything went ok, and the file needed was there.

Basically:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git

$ cd pybind11

$ mkdir build

$ cd build

$ cmake .. 

$ make -j`nproc`

$ make check

$ make -j`nproc` install
```